# replaced input with select validation jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an input field which is being validated,, but if i check specific checkbox, it disappears by `display:none;` and the select field comes in place. But when i submit the form, it gets the select value, but  in query the input field value is requested too. So query looks like that

```
form=contact-us-form-2&source=contact-us-form-2&department=support&summary=Segmentation&summary=&message=asd
```

the form

```
<select id="summary" name="summary" class="required">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please select subject</option>
    <option value="Select one">Select one</option>
    <option value="Select two">Select two</option>
    <option value="Select three">Select three</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

and my input field

```
<input type="text" name="summary" id="summarise-text-input">
```

If i delete manually the hidden input field, it submits the form successfully.

Comment: Besides hiding the `textbox`, have you tried adding `disabled` attribute to it?

Comment: You've tagged the question with jQuery yet have shown us no jQuery code whatsoever.

Comment: could you indicate us how the query should look like, and how it looks like now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an input hidden, and fill it with the input text content with javascript.

```
<select id="summary" name="summary" class="required">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please select subject</option>
    <option value="Select one">Select one</option>
    <option value="Select two">Select two</option>
    <option value="Select three">Select three</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select> 
<input type="text" name="summary" id="summarise-text-input_show">
<input type="hidden" name="summary" id="summarise-text-input">
```

javascript :

```
$(function() {
    $("#summary").change(function() {
        $("#summarise-text-input_show, #summarise-text-input").val($(this).find(":selected").text());
    });
});
```

Actually, I'm not sure I really understood your question…